# Dotnet Core Pubnub not sending Message

Tags: flutter, .net-core, pubnub

i want to send message from .net to pubnub and receive from flutter using pubnub to get message but some how .dot net does not send it out. am i missing some thing ?

C# Send Message from Pubnub

```
        PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
        pnConfiguration.SubscribeKey = "sub-key";
        pnConfiguration.PublishKey = "pub-key";
        pnConfiguration.Uuid = "123";
        Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub(pnConfiguration);


        Dictionary<string, string> message = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        message.Add("msg", "Hello world");

        pubnub.Publish()
                .Channel("ChannelID123")
                .Message(message)
                .Execute(new PNPublishResultExt((publishResult, publishStatus) =>
                {
                    if (!publishStatus.Error)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }));
```

Flutter Receive Message

```
final pubnub = PubNub(
    defaultKeyset: Keyset(
      subscribeKey: 'sub-key',
      publishKey: 'pub-key',
      uuid: UUID('123'),
    ),
  );


var subscription = pubnub.subscribe(channels: {'ChannelID123'});
    subscription.messages.listen((envelope) {
      print(envelope.content);
    });
    print(subscription);
```

Comment: How do you know C# SDK is not sending the message? Are you getting an error or just not receiving the message in your Flutter client? Can you enable PN SDK logging and reproduce and provide logs? [C# SDK Logs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/c-sharp/troubleshooting) - [Dart SDK Logs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/dart/troubleshooting) - And you can use the PubNub Dev Console to subscribe to the channel and publish a message to test the send/receive success: pubnub.com/docs/console - submit logs and copy of this SO post to support@pubnub.com for further investigation.

Comment: i finally found a solution, that need to subscribe only publish only the message can be send. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you just said, but glad you have a solution. You can create an official answer if you can provide the details of your solution.